# html returned by ajax not rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 files, A and B. In A I do ajax like

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "html",
    url: "example.com/B.html",
    success: function (data) {

        $('#somewhere').html(data);

    }
});
```

The content did loaded but a plugin of jquery is not been executed, it's a slider. I got an error `$(..).slid()` is not a function, but when I run B separately it worked. Any idea why?

Comment: guessing there is javascript that makes the slider work and it is on page B but missing from page A

Comment: place a `console.log(data)` inside your success callback, and show the console output

Comment: @23tux As I said I got the entire B.

Comment: @ScottSelby why does that doesn't execute in page A? I run B separately it just worked.

Comment: I might be missing the point here, but why are you doing it? if you have two pages and you want the content of `b` inside `a`, why not put it in `a` too? it's not clear from your question why you'd make the users suffer the ajax call? is there something else going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are using it, can be optimized as:

```
$('#somewhere').load('B.html');
```

which just loads the `B.html` in the element with id `#somewhere`.

And if you want to execute/initialize some plugin then you can use a callback in the `.load(url, callback)` like this:

```
$('#somewhere').load('B.html', function(){
    $.getScript('yourscriptpath', function(data){
       // do something here.
    })
});
```

Comment: @AliceXu Although you don't need to use `$.getScript` take a look at this plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/kulD7B66fFFOzFgHZ0gs?p=preview

Comment: but getScript solved my problem. normal alert will work but not a plugin's js file.